# Can´t establish connection between Server and Client using SocketIO

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I`m trying to connect to a socket but I get Error:

**GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OhMOw8Z 404 0.180 ms - 149**

On the server side I have:

server.js

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const http = require('http')
const app = require("./app");

require("./routes/auth.routes")(app);
require("./routes/socket.routes")(app);

const server = http.createServer(app)

server.listen(PORT, () => {

  console.log(`Listening on PORT:${PORT}`);
});

module.exports = server
```

Then I have a data controller that tries to iniciate the connection to the socket.

data.controller.js

```
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
  cookie: true,
})

const getPrices = async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)

  console.log('SERVER')

  io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    console.log("Socket Connection Established");
    
  })



};
```

On the client side I have this:

Socket.js

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:3001', {
    transportOptions: {
        polling: {
            extraHeaders: {
                'X-Auth-Token': `${token}`,
            },
        },
    }
}
)
export default socket;
```

Data.js (ehe I click the button, makes an http and executes the getPrices function from above)

```
import socket from "./Socket";
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            const token = TokenService.getUser()
            await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/socket", {
                token
            });

            console.log('GET DATA!')


           socket.emit('connection')

        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Data Error: ", error.message);
        }
    };
```

Any recommendation about this?

Answer (score 0):

io.on("connection") is for socket initialization. connection is a special event, it's not an event that we create on our own. So if you want to check it on client side you would have to use like below:

```
// server-side
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(socket.id); // ojIckSD2jqNzOqIrAGzL
});

// client-side
socket.on("connect", () => {
  console.log(socket.id); // ojIckSD2jqNzOqIrAGzL
});
```